# My released App is not loading correctly from the first time

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, release

I am facing a problem with my App, after releasing the App bundle & load it to play store... I downloaded my own App to check it if working properly ... i was surprised that the App is not loading correctly for the first time... & I have to clear stop the app & then optimize my device then it will load correctly , the case i am facing is
[image: WhatsApp Image 2021-10-28 at 9.18.04 PM.jpeg]

while the main screen suppose to be like this
[image: WhatsApp Image 2021-10-28 at 9.18.03 PM.jpeg]

I updated my flutter, android studio, but still one error is still shown in the project structure which is this
[image: Capture.PNG]

is this the reason about this behavior of my App & how I can solve this issue.... I had to unpublished my App....
please help

Comment: Have you try `dart pub cache repair`?

Comment: actually no... I will try it now

Comment: after run the dart pub cache repair, now i have two errors Library KotlinJavaRuntime is not used [Fix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Main issue is I was using sizer2.0.15 package to make responsive cards for the main screen, and i was using `const` modifier in my main page as the following code

```
return Sizer(
  builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreenPage(),
    );
  },
);
```

I made a very silly experiment & it worked, I removed the `const` modifier from the `MaterialApp` in main.dart, then it start working properly on release version... during coding if a `const` modifier is added to a Container, sizedBox, Font,....ets it will show an error, and since this problem happened only in the main screen loading ... I removed the `const`modifier & i got the result i want...

```
 return Sizer(
  builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreenPage(),
    );
  },
);
```